# Unicode vs. UTF-8

Tags: powershell, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I believe Windows currently defaults to UTF-16 for “Unicode”, but that this may not be the case in the future.

For this reason, would it be better to use

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($someByteArray)
```

instead of the following?:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($someByteArray)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> this may not be the case in the future.

`Unicode` isn't a potentially-variable encoding; it's just Microsoft's (sadly misleading) name for UTF-16LE.

It isn't going to change. Even if Microsoft moved towards implementing Windows APIs natively in UTF-8 or UTF-32 (something there's no sign of ever happening), `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` would have to remain UTF-16LE as that is how it is defined by the .NET specification.

> would it be better to use `UTF8` instead of `Unicode`?

Use `UTF8` if the byte array contains UTF-8-encoded bytes, and use `Unicode` if they are in UTF-16LE.

If you get to choose what encoding is used to store data at rest, UTF-8 is usually the better choice for space efficiency reasons.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thankyou. However how can you be sure that Microsoft won't change it? Aren't they allowed to change the .NET spec if they want to? What implications would this have if they did?

Comment: They can certainly change any API definition in a new version of .NET, but they have never hinted that the definition of Unicode, char or String are subject to change, so it would be a big compatibility-breaking surprise. In any case MS are *really* reticent to break old APIs. The last time there was a change of internal string encoding was over the transition from Windows 9x to NT, and the old (ANSI) APIs are available to this day. (We are still dealing with the legacy of this, with C-stdlib applications still defaulting to the ANSI string interfaces, and broken UTF-8 support in msvcrt.)

Answer (score 2):

First, yes [Windows defaults to UTF-16](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding(v=vs.110).aspx). Personally I would use UTF-8, because most of the applications I write have to communicate with Linux applications or some form of http so UTF-8 is more likely.

Besides even if all your code is used with Microsoft systems it's easy to convert to UTF-8 and a simple substitute regular expression could change everything over to Unicode (UTF-16) if .NET started requiring it.